# Update statement - where conditions are not being met

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am running the below sql statement but it looks as though every row is being updated and the conditions are ignored. My conditions for a row to be updated are that:

- instrument_static.client_sentiment_long >50
- market_data.days_change => 0

The query:

```
UPDATE market_data
    SET sentiment_inline = 'TRUE'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT s.epic,s.client_sentiment_long,s.client_sentiment_short,m.days_change,m.sentiment_inline
                  FROM instrument_static s JOIN 
                       market_data m
                       ON m.epic = 'MARKET:' || s.epic 
                  WHERE s.client_sentiment_long > 50 AND m.days_change >=0
                 );
```

Comment: What is `=>0` supposed to be doing?  I assume you intend `>= 0`.

Comment: Yes good spot let me correct that

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want a *correlated* subquery:

```
UPDATE market_data m
    SET sentiment_inline = 'TRUE'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM instrument_static s 
                  WHERE m.epic = 'MARKET:' || s.epic AND
                        s.client_sentiment_long > 50 AND 
                        m.days_change >= 0
                 );
```

This ties the condition in the subquery to the specific row you might want to update.  Otherwise, the condition is checking for the existing of *any* row in `market_data` -- and that is not what you want.

I would move the final condition to the outer `WHERE`, so this reads as:

```
    WHERE m.days_change >= 0 AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM instrument_static s 
                  WHERE m.epic = 'MARKET:' || s.epic AND
                        s.client_sentiment_long > 50                          
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon saved me again. Thanks for taking the time to explain it too, that's very kind of you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a Postgresql like `join` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE market_data m
SET sentiment_inline = 'TRUE'
FROM instrument_static s
WHERE m.epic = 'MARKET:' || s.epic JOIN AND s.client_sentiment_long > 50 AND m.days_change >= 0
```